# accessing a child website from parent website

Tags: authentication, web, communication

I have a requirement as below.
I have a parent website which has its own login implementation .I have a link to a child website on a page.The child website can be accessed only form the parent site.If user accesses the child URL directly he should get a page not found page.
Also both parent and child sites can send-receive data between them.The child website can be accessed by multiple parent site.
Can you please let me know how we can achieve session functionality in above scenario.
How we can use web services in above scenario?
What parameters I need to consider for managing the communication between these site.

Please let me know if I need to provide some more information

Comment: In addition to the above requirement,one major requirement is as below.I have a website Parent.com and child.com. I want to provide automatic authenticate for child.com when a user logged in from Parent.com website if the user will trying to open child.com and he is already logged in to the parent.com website then no need to show the login screen of child.com it will automatic authenticate that user and he will able enter the child.com website freely